# Transpose part of SQL results to consolidate records

Tags: mysql, sql

I’m working on a project and it’s become a bit more complicated than I’m able to deal with. I have a piece of SQL that inner joins to several tables. One of these tables returns communication means for each individual (telephone number, radio call sign, pager, for example).

Once I’ve implemented this code, the SQL (quite rightly) returns multiple records for each individual, depending on which comms fields they’ve got filled out. So a search for myself would return:

```
Name  |  COMM_VALUE    | COMM_RID
Nick  |  07123 456789  |   5
Nick  |  0965          |   6
Nick  |  328493        |   7
```

Where as, I need:

```
Name  |  Mobile        |   Radio    |  Pager
Nick  |  07123 456789  |   0965     |  328493
Bob   |  etc etc etc
```

This is part of much larger table so my question is how do I add these columns to my existing SQL, I looked in to nested, subqueries, and unions but it’s an age since I did SQL and even my basic progress has been testing my capability.

I envisage something like the following but not sure of the keywords I need to achieve this:

```
Select
  PRP.FIRSTNAME + ‘ ‘ + PRP.SURNAME AS FULLNAME,
  RDP.POSTNAME,
  RRP.REMARKS,
  */ NEW COLUMNS */
      (SELECT COMM_VALUE FROM PERREC_COMMS WHERE COMM_RID = ‘6’) AS RADIO
```

The above (edited) code does yield results, but not quite as I anticipated:

```
Name  |  RADIO
Nick  |  0965
Nick  |  null
Nick  |  null
```

The above is then repeated for each person, with the other fields appearing correctly although duplicated on each row.

How can I consolidate these results to one row (exclude the ‘null’ results)?

Comment: There's no pcomm_rid here.

Comment: Typo, sorry. Will check your link

Comment: There's no comm _rid here either

Comment: There is a comm_rid field in PERREC_COMMS. PERREC_COMMS is inner joined later in the statement. I’ve not included the full statement as it’s too long to retype. (SO is banned at work ;-( )

Comment: From my research, I’m suspecting that PIVOT is required. However, i then need to merge the pivoted results with the rest of my query, and I think my brain is going to melt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pivot the data.  One method is conditional aggregation.  For this purpose, I would recommend:

```
select name,
       group_concat(case when comm_rid = 5 then comm_value end) as what_5_means,
       group_concat(case when comm_rid = 6 then comm_value end) as radio,
       group_concat(case when comm_rid = 7 then comm_value end) as whateve_7_means
from . . .
group by name;
```

I have no idea from the question what `from` clause to use.

This uses `group_concat()` rather than `max()` just in case someone has multiple means of communications with the same type.

Comment: Thanks, group_concat not recognised function, will try max()

Comment: @TheMiddle . . . Use `max()`.  However, your question is tagged mysql, and `group_concat()` has been in MySQL for a long time.  You should be sure to tag the question with the database you are really using.

Comment: Thanks, max has helped and the case statement has got most of what I’ve needed done. I just need to remove the null values now but they are being stubborn!